Google Play Console Testing Requirements Completed, but "Apply for Production" Button is Not Enabled
Google Play Console Testing Requirements Completed, but "Apply for Production" Button is Not Enabled
Question:
I've been working on an app and have met all the testing requirements in the Google Play Console. Specifically:

Testing period: 14 days
Number of testers: 20

However, the "Apply for Production" button is still not enabled. I've double-checked the requirements and everything seems to be in order.


Are there any hidden or less obvious requirements that I might be missing?

The app has been tested thoroughly by all 20 testers

Can you help me with 20 testers too?
